# Tor network won't connect - torrent secured network

Tags: proxy

I'm completely new tot this. 
I can't seem to connect to the Tor network.
My network is secured against torrents. When somebody tries to use torrents everybody's internet slows down and it does not work. Maybe that's it? Can I get around this?
I have no proxy, I have Windows 10.
I tried some stuff with bridges and "Fascistfirewall1" but as I know nothing about all this, I most likely have made it worse.

Comment: You may want to share more details about what the exact errors you are encountering are, are you using the Tor Browser Bundle or is it a manual configuration, etc. In any case, you may want to temporarily disable your firewall and see if you can connect to TOR, if you believe that to be the issue.